# Porting Arduino Comm Data into .txt

Tags: java, io, arduino, processing

I'm trying to dump signal data over the arduino's channel using a Processing script. Currently my Processing code reads the data over COM3 and I'm running into an issue with the Processing script whereby it only saves one line into the .txt and constantly refreshes that line when I open it. The arduino code for the accelerometer/gyroscope signal and Processing script were found from Sparkfun's site:

```
#include "SparkFunLSM6DS3.h"
#include "Wire.h"
#include "SPI.h"

LSM6DS3 myIMU; //Default constructor is I2C, addr 0x6B

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(1000); //relax...
  Serial.println("Processor came out of reset.\n");
//  Serial.println(value);

  //Call .begin() to configure the IMU
  myIMU.begin();
  //Over-ride default settings if desired
  myIMU.settings.gyroEnabled = 1;  //Can be 0 or 1
  myIMU.settings.gyroRange = 2000;   //Max deg/s.  Can be: 125, 245
  myIMU.settings.gyroSampleRate = 833;   //Hz.  Can be: 13, 26, 52, 104,  208, 416, 833, 1666
  myIMU.settings.gyroBandWidth = 200;  //Hz.  Can be: 50, 100, 200, 400;
  myIMU.settings.gyroFifoEnabled = 1;  //Set to include gyro in FIFO  
  myIMU.settings.gyroFifoDecimation = 1;  //set 1 for on /1

myIMU.settings.accelEnabled = 1;
myIMU.settings.accelRange = 16;      //Max G force readable.  Can be: 2, 4, 8, 16
myIMU.settings.accelSampleRate = 833;  //Hz.  Can be: 13, 26, 52, 104, 208, 416, 833, 1666, 3332, 6664, 13330
myIMU.settings.accelBandWidth = 200;  //Hz.  Can be: 50, 100, 200, 400;
myIMU.settings.accelFifoEnabled = 1;  //Set to include accelerometer in the FIFO
myIMU.settings.accelFifoDecimation = 1;  //set 1 for on /1
myIMU.settings.tempEnabled = 1;

//Non-basic mode settings
myIMU.settings.commMode = 1;

//FIFO control settings
myIMU.settings.fifoThreshold = 100;  //Can be 0 to 4096 (16 bit bytes)
myIMU.settings.fifoSampleRate = 50;  //Hz.  Can be: 10, 25, 50, 100, 200, 400, 800, 1600, 3300, 6600
myIMU.settings.fifoModeWord = 6;  //FIFO mode.
//FIFO mode.  Can be:
//  0 (Bypass mode, FIFO off)
//  1 (Stop when full)
//  3 (Continuous during trigger)
//  4 (Bypass until trigger)
//  6 (Continous mode)
}

void loop()
{
  //Get all parameters
  Serial.print("\nAccelerometer:\n");
  Serial.print(" X = ");
  Serial.println(myIMU.readFloatAccelX(), 4);
  Serial.print(" Y = ");
  Serial.println(myIMU.readFloatAccelY(), 4);
  Serial.print(" Z = ");
  Serial.println(myIMU.readFloatAccelZ(), 4);

  Serial.print("\nGyroscope:\n");
  Serial.print(" X = ");
  Serial.println(myIMU.readFloatGyroX(), 4);
  Serial.print(" Y = ");
  Serial.println(myIMU.readFloatGyroY(), 4);
  Serial.print(" Z = ");
  Serial.println(myIMU.readFloatGyroZ(), 4);

  Serial.print("\nThermometer:\n");
  Serial.print(" Degrees C = ");
  Serial.println(myIMU.readTempC(), 4);
  Serial.print(" Degrees F = ");
  Serial.println(myIMU.readTempF(), 4);

  delay(1000);
}
```

My Processing Script.

```
import processing.serial.*;
import java.io.*;
Serial myPort;
String val;
int Dummy = 1;

void setup() {


  size(500,500);
  //String portName = Serial.list()[2];

  myPort = new Serial(this , "COM3", 9600);

}
void draw()
{
  if (myPort.available() > 0)
  {val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');}
      //while (myPort.available() > 0){
      try {

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Output1.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
        pw.println(val);
        pw.close();

      //ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Output.bin"));
     // os.writeObject(val);
      //while (Dummy > 0) {os.close();}




        }
        catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println("ERMAC");
       }

  println(val);
}
```

I'm new to java and not very familiar with the I/O streaming libraries. Any advice offered would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new `FileWriter` and `PrintWriter` every time you detect a new line. Creating a new `FileWriter` and `PrintWriter` **creates a new empty file with that name**. That's why you only ever see the one line in the file.

Instead, you should **declare** your writers at the sketch-level, and then only create them **once**, at the beginning of your sketch. You might do this in your `setup()` function, for example:

```
FileWriter fw;
PrintWriter pw;

void setup() {
  size(500,500);
  myPort = new Serial(this , "COM3", 9600);
  FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Output1.txt");
  PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
}
```

And then, since the variables are declared at the sketch level, you can use them in your `draw()` function just like you are now, but without recreating them every time:

```
void draw(){
  if (myPort.available() > 0){
    val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');}

     try {
        pw.println(val);
     }
     catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("ERMAC");
     }

     println(val);
  }
}
```

**Alternatively**, you could just use the `FileWriter` constructor that accepts a `boolean` value:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Output1.txt", true);
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
pw.println(val);
pw.close();
```

This tells the `FileWriter` to **append** the data instead of creating a new file. More info in the [Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.lang.String,%20boolean)).